# Jquery scroll to anchor only if id exists

Tags: jquery

I create a validation box when a form is complete, i reload the page to show it, and would like to automatically scroll to the validation box.
I added an id to my box "invitation", and add this code in my js files :

```
$(document).scrollTop( $("#invitation").offset().top );
```

It works ! But when i'm on a page without the invitation id, my website is not working correctly.

**How to scroll to this anchor only if it exists ?**

Answer (score 1):

Add it in if loop.

```
if ($("#invitation").length){
    $(document).scrollTop( $("#invitation").offset().top );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a conditional that checks length of the jQuery object. No length means no matching element found

```
var $invitation =  $("#invitation")
if($invitation.length){
   $(document).scrollTop( $invitation.offset().top );
}
```